# C# Restore a form property value that has been changed

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, propertychanged

I have a main form. Using the KeyDown event I've been able to make the form go Full Screen at the user's request (by pressing CTRL + ALT + ENTER).

So, I need: 1) when the form is not at "Full Screen mode" and the user presses CTRL + ALT + ENTER, as expected, the form goes Full Screen, and 2) when the form is already at "Full Screen mode" and user presses CTRL + ALT + ENTER, the form should go back the way it was before.

Turning the form to FullScreen is done. The problem is, now I have to determine whether the properties of size, location, and form border style (any of them) where changed, and then restore them to whatever values they had before I pressed the keys, so I can undone those property changes.

```
private bool IsFullScreen() //Is form at "FullScreen Mode"?
{
    return (this.Height == Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height 
    && this.Width == Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width &&                         
    this.FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None);
}

private void FullScreen(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt & e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    {
        if (!IsFullScreen()) //Form is resized to FullScreen, only if it's not already 'fullscreened'
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            /*Form goes back to whatever size, location, and form border style 
            it had before I pressed CTRL + ALT + ENTER*/
        }    
    }
}
```

How could this be achieved? Is there a class / method I could use? (I think PropertyChanged might be the one, but I can't still find how to restore the properties I want) Thank you.

P.S: If you're wondering why I didn't just set the window as "maximized" and the form border as none, and be done with it, turns out the professor just doesn't like that solution and want us to 'fullscreen' it for real and not 'quickly make it look like it'. 
The only thing I'm having trouble with is to make the form go back to the previous state before it was 'fullscreened'.

Comment: at start what will be mode : full or normal ?

Comment: @utility Normal. Then, if the user wishes so, they can press CTRL + ALT + ENTER, that makes it go full. If they press it again, the form should go back to the previous size, location, and form border style (That's what the problem is... Bear in mind that maybe the user changed any of those -specially the size one -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without using the Size parameters. The only thing you are doing to make it **truly** full screen is removing the form border.

```
if (!IsFullScreen()) //Form is resized to FullScreen, only if it's not already 'fullscreened'
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        /*Form goes back to whatever size, location, and form border style 
        it had before I pressed CTRL + ALT + ENTER*/
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Single;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

If you still want to maintain the state information, you could save them to member variables and use their values, when you want to reverse them.

```
    private Point previousLocation;
private Size previousSize; 
private void FullScreen()
{

    if (!IsFullScreen()) //Form is resized to FullScreen, only if it's not already 'fullscreened'
    {
        previousLocation = this.Location;
        previousSize = this.Size;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        /*Form goes back to whatever size, location, and form border style 
        it had before I pressed CTRL + ALT + ENTER*/
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Location = previousLocation;
        this.Size = previousSize;
    }
}
```

Please check for nulls or variables not being assigned.

Comment: My professor specifically forbade doing it like this, just because "he doesn't like it that way" and want us to do it by sizing and stuff. Turns out he wants it to be 'fullscreened' for real, not just 'made look like it's fullscreened when it's really not'. He said he would grade as 0 any project done like you're suggesting (I don't know what's the problem, it's the same result)

If I could, I would done it already, instead of asking around :(
Thanks you for taking the time anyway.

Comment: @soulblazer Updated the answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: DUH! I'm so tired I didn't even thought about it... It was so obvious! Thank you! Maybe I should just save this code and stop for the day and sleep. I should be more tired that I realized. 

I still don't like how the professor gives zeros for projects that are "different" from way he likes... Well, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First set the form to `normal` mode and design its dimensions.
Latter place a button to maximize the form.On clicking button to `maximize` check the property of the form whether `maximise/normal` and change the size mode of the form.

> The only thing to keep in mind is if the focus is not on the form your
>   shortcut keys will trigger system shortcuts